# When to create maven submodules

Tags: java, maven

At the moment I'm working in a project which contains out of 260 maven submodules under one parent pom. This seems to slow down the build. That's why I came up with the question when should I use submodules and when shouldn't I use it.

Comment: The question is: Is really the thing about the number of modules taking time to built or might other reason the real issue here? Unit/Integration Tests? Slow Machines? RAM ? Versions of plugins/Maven you are using etc. ? It's not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Introduction to the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation) says:

> If you have several Maven projects, and they all have similar configurations, you can refactor your projects by pulling out those similar configurations and making a parent project. Thus, all you have to do is to let your Maven projects inherit that parent project, and those configurations would then be applied to all of them.
>
> And if you have a group of projects that are built or processed together, you can create a parent project and have that parent project declare those projects as its modules. By doing so, you'd only have to build the parent and the rest will follow.

Create submodules when:

- projects share the same configuration, to avoid configuration duplication
- projects are interconnected, to make building easier

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit broad because it is hard to set a general rule.

My rule of thumb:

"A multi-module project consists of those modules/artifacts that should *always* be built together".

If you just want to share configuration, you can use a parent POM without using multi-module.